# Regex to validate hashtags (#) ignoring URLs that contain anchor (#)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have any type of text entries:

```
#teste

#teste:

##teste

oi esse é um tempo com #blalbalb no meio da #gxD

https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2019/09/16/precos-do-#petroleo-disparam-apos-ataques-a-instalacoes-na-arabia-saudita.ghtml

http://nexus.dfdff.com/-#browse:central

http://nexus.ssdff.com/#browse/browse:npm-group

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

I need to identify only texts that contain `#`. The difficulty is that URLs might also contain `#`.

My regular expression so far: https://regex101.com/r/LLHo0w/3

`\B(\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!\/|\-|\:)`

Wrong match: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/**#inbox** some text **#hi**

Correct match: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox some text **#hi**

```
\B(\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!\/|\-|\:)

var html = "<a href="#" data-timeline-action="search">$1</a>"
var text= "vamos ser #amigos pode ser? https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"
text.replace(/\B(\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!\/|\-|\:)/ig, html);
```

Comment: `^` character is starts-with, if you use starts-with that should negate the `#` that are found within url. Maybe this? `\B(^\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!\/|\-|\:)`

Comment: thanks for help! but doesnt work for me https://regex101.com/r/LLHo0w/4

Comment: Welcome to SO! How about `(?<=\s|^)#\S+?(?=\s)` or `(?<=\s|^)#\S+`?

Comment: this https://regex101.com/r/LLHo0w/5 almost work, but the regex capture de space before #

Comment: this (?<=\s|^)#\S+?(?=\s) works perfectly, but in my JS, the replace doenst works ```text.replace(/(?:<=\s|^)#\S+?(?:=\s)/ig, html);
"vamos ser #amigos pode ser?" ``` 
I expect ```"vamos ser <a href="#" data-timeline-action="search">#amigos</a> pode ser?"```

Comment: See my answer--I think the simpler version should work for you (let me know if not and I'll update).

Comment: If you can be sure that there is a whitespace between the comment and the text, it can be as simple as this: `^(#.*)|\s(#.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting hashtags, using spaces as the delimiter seems much less brittle than a blacklist of URL characters:

```
/(?<=#|\s|^)(#[^\s#]+)/g
```

This uses a positive lookbehind to verify a space or beginning of line before the literal `#` (disregard multiple `#`s), then gobble non-space, non-hashtag characters to capture the tag itself.

```js
const text = `#teste
#teste:
##teste
oi esse é um tempo com #blalbalb no meio da #gxD
https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2019/09/16/precos-do-#petroleo-disparam-apos-ataques-a-instalacoes-na-arabia-saudita.ghtml
http://nexus.dfdff.com/-#browse:central
http://nexus.ssdff.com/#browse/browse:npm-group
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`;

const pattern = /(?<=#|\s|^)(#[^\s#]+)/g;

console.log(text.match(pattern));
console.log(text.replace(pattern, "<REPLACED: '$1'>"));

console.log(
  "vamos ser #amigos pode ser? https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox".replace(
    pattern, '<a href="#" data-timeline-action="search">$1</a>'
  )
);
```

If your browser [doesn't support lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can use an extra capturing group to ensure the replacement preserves the prefix:

```
/(\s#+|\s|^)(#[^\s#]+)/g
```

```js
const text = `#teste
#teste:
##teste
oi esse é um tempo com #blalbalb no meio da #gxD
https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2019/09/16/precos-do-#petroleo-disparam-apos-ataques-a-instalacoes-na-arabia-saudita.ghtml
http://nexus.dfdff.com/-#browse:central
http://nexus.ssdff.com/#browse/browse:npm-group
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`;

const pattern = /(\s#+|\s|^)(#[^\s#]+)/g;

for (let m; m = pattern.exec(text); console.log(m));

console.log("---");
console.log(text.replace(pattern, "$1<REPLACED: '$2'>"));

console.log(
  "vamos ser #amigos pode ser? https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox".replace(
    pattern, '$1<a href="#" data-timeline-action="search">$2</a>'
  )
);
```

Comment: tried your last regex, since the first one will not work for my I.E. users. 
this is how I adapted it to work for me now:

/(?:\s#+|\s|^)(#[^\s#<]+)/ig

the big deal is that the blank spaces and line breaks before the # are being returned in the captured group and I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Not sure I follow the problem exactly. In the second version, use `$2` to access the hashtag. `$1` contains the filler before the hashtag itself. So as you can see, the substitution becomes a bit more complicated, using `$1` to re-populate the spaces, then the HTML link tag, then the `$2` hashtag group, then the closing tag. Can you explain why this isn't working for IE?

Comment: using the group $2, this regex working perfectly on IE. I wasn't using group capture.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this one and looks like it works:

```
/(?:^|\s)(#[a-z\d-_]+)/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to match all the urls  and capture the hashtags in a capturing group.

```
https?:\/\/\S+|(?:^|\s+)(#[a-zA-Z]+)
```

In parts

- `https?:\/\/` Match http, optional `s` and `://`
- `\S+` Match 1+ no whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `(?:^|\s+)` Assert the start of the string or match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(#[a-zA-Z]+)` Capture in **group 1** matching `#` and 1+ chars a-zA-Z

(use `\S+` instead of `[a-zA-Z]+` to match non whitespace chars)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEWim3/1)

```js
const regex = /https?:\/\/\S+|(?:^|\s+)(#[a-zA-Z]+)/g;
const str = `#teste
#teste:
##teste
oi esse é um tempo com #blalbalb no meio da #gxD
https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2019/09/16/precos-do-#petroleo-disparam-apos-ataques-a-instalacoes-na-arabia-saudita.ghtml
http://nexus.dfdff.com/-#browse:central
http://nexus.ssdff.com/#browse/browse:npm-group
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (undefined !== m[1]) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```